# Error installing and updating software with "sudo apt upgrade"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am quite new to linux and i run POP! OS. Recently when I tried to run "sudo apt upgrade" I got this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.13-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.17~) but it is not going to be installed
 libavahi-client3:i386 : Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.101) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgbm1:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 199) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried to run

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

but this just gives the same error along with this

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Does anyone know what I could do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you stepped through each dependency and tried installing the update versions?

Comment: Try sudo apt update, then upgrade.